# Change default compiler in make

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, compilation

In my Ubuntu machine, I have a makefile, and I want to compile the project to a different compiler then the default `gcc` compiler.

I read a lot about it, and I tried different methods, including:

1. Adding CC=`<other_compiler>` in the command line: `make CC=<other_compiler>`
2. Adding `CC` and `CXX` as an environment variable in the command line from which I execute make.
3. Adding CC=`<other_compiler>` inside `makefile`

But all of them didn't change the fact that the default compiler (`gcc`) was called, instead of mine compiler.

Any ideas what could have I been missing, and where else can I check?

Comment: If none of those work, then the makefile you're using must not be using those variables to compile the code.  Without seeing the makefile recipe that invokes the compiler, there's no way for us to say more than that.  But if you wrote your recipe to run `gcc ...` directly, rather than using the variable `$(CC)` etc., then no amount of setting variables will change the compiler.